# Forced to use template?

Tags: html, dart, innerhtml

This code from Dart worries me:

```
bool get isTemplate => tagName == 'TEMPLATE' || _isAttributeTemplate;

  void _ensureTemplate() {
    if (!isTemplate) {
      throw new UnsupportedError('$this is not a template.');
    }
...
```

Does this mean that the only way I can modify my document is to make it html5?

What if I want to modify an html4 document and set innerHtml in a div, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking about the code in dart:html `Element`?

The method you are referring to is only called by the library itself, and only in methods where `isTemplate` has to be true, for example [this one](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#ref). If you follow this link, you can also read what other fields/methods work like this.

`innerHtml` is a field in every subclass of `Element` which supports it, for example [`DivElement`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/DivElement.html#innerHtml)

Example:

```dart
DivElement myDiv1 = new DivElement();
myDiv1.innerHtml = "<p>I am a DIV!</p>";
query("#some_div_id").innerHtml = "<p>Hey, me too!</p>";
```